# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory (Unsolved with python-devel)

Tags: compiling, python3, anaconda, caffe

When trying to compile pycaffe on Ubuntu 16.04, with Anaconda 3.6 installed I get the following error:

```
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:52: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to install the python-devel packages with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

But even after trying with each of those separately the same error occurs.

The correct PATH seems to be added in .bashrc

```
export PATH="home/jdevezas/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

And in Caffe's makefile.config I have

```
# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
#PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.

ANACONDA_HOME := /home/jdevezas/anaconda

#PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
#            $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
#            $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
 PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
 PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

I have also tried with Python 2.7 with no results.
I have checked the /usr/include/python3.5m and Python.h is there. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `python.h` instead ?

Comment: I haven't but I have checked the directories where Python.h is and it is spelled with a capital P (also the error spells it with P). But I'll give it a try and come back with a reply if it works.

Comment: I have however tried running "python-config --cflags" and it returns:

-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

Nothing related to Python 3.6... Could this be it?

Answer (score 0):

Updated (2021-01-11): `Python.h` header is now in `$CONDA_PREFIX/include/python3.Y` (where Y is minor version) in case of Linux or `$CONDA_PREFIX/include` in Windows.

---

Old answer: `python.h` header is in `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/include/python3.6m` directory.

Comment: $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/ only have jupyter folder in my case

Comment: @nirala , now the location is different. `include` directory is in root of `$CONDA_PREFIX`

Answer (score 0):

For tracking down the packages a file is in, use

```
apt-file search Python.h
```

The list (for Ubuntu 20.04) shows two likely candidates for the latest python version:  libpython3.8-dev and pypy3-dev.
The package you need to install is libpython3.8-dev

Install apt-file with

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then update its database:

```
apt-file update
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the python folder was situated in `/opt/anaconda3/include/`, which I found by

```
$ which conda
/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

the variable `$CONDA_PREFIX` was empty in my case, as

```
$ echo $CONDA_PREFIX
```

printed just an empty line.